# Strongly Typed Configuration Settings not mapped

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to setup a strongly typed configuration setting in my ASP.NET Core 2.1 application.

In my startup.cs file I have the following code:

```
services.Configure<AzureStorageConfig>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureStorageConfig"));
```

My setting class AzureStorageConfig is looking like this:

```
public class AzureStorageConfig
{
    public string StorageConnectionString { get; internal set; }
}
```

My appSetting.json:

```
{
 "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "System": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
 },
 "AzureStorageConfig": {
    "StorageConnectionString": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
 }
}
```

When I run the code, my AzureStorageConfig.StorageConnectionString is always null.

If I set a breakpoint in the startup.cs file, I can see that the settings are there:

[image]

But when injecting the AzureStorageConfig, it's null.

```
public class RestaurantService : IRestaurantService
{
    private AzureStorageConfig m_Config;

    public RestaurantService(IOptions<AzureStorageConfig> config)
    {
        m_Config = config.Value;
    }
}
```

[image]

I think I have everything like described here: https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/May/23/Strongly-Typed-Configuration-Settings-in-ASPNET-Core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `StorageConnectionString` property has an `internal` setter, but this will need to be `public` in order for the binder to use it when attempting to bind from your `Configuration` instance:

```
public class AzureStorageConfig
{
    public string StorageConnectionString { get; set; }
}
```